# Get Facebook's friends birthdays in Objective C

Tags: facebook

i found a site like graph.facebook.com but I cannot understand this API, so I wanted to know if there's a way to get the friends birthday (e.g. as an HTTP Request) ?
Please help,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just glancing over the documentation, it seems that you would need the user's authorization:

Look at the user api: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api:

The Graph API as such allows you to easily access **all public information** about an object. For example, https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor (Bret Taylor) returns all the public information about Bret. For example a user's first name, last name and profile picture are publicly available.

**To get additional information about a user, you must first get their permission. At a high level, you need to get an access token for the Facebook user**. After you obtain the access token for the user, you can perform authorized requests on behalf of that user by including the access token in your Graph API requests

Here is an example done in FQL: [Fetching friends' birthdays from facebook profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243956/fetching-friends-birthdays-from-facebook-profile)

FQL: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/